# How to get the sum of child records using web api odata?

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api

How do I return the total of the OrderItems prices (ItemTotalPrice) in web api odata?

It looks like web api odata does not support $apply as described here: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs01/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs01.html#_Aggregation_Methods_1

I have an web api odata query like:

```
http://localhost:29446/odata/OrderItems
```

which returns the following json:

```
{
  "odata.metadata": "http://localhost:29446/odata/$metadata#OrderItems",
  "value": [{
    "OrderItemID": 17,
    "ItemDescription": "test",
    "ItemQty": 1,
    "ItemUnitPrice": "1.10",
    "ItemTaxGroup": 1,
    "ItemTotalTax": "0.10",
    "ItemTotalPrice": "1.22",
    "ItemSubProgram": 1,
    "ItemAccount": 1,
    "ItemActualCost": "1.22",
    "OrderID": 3
  }, {
    "OrderItemID": 18,
    "ItemDescription": "test",
    "ItemQty": 1,
    "ItemUnitPrice": "1.10",
    "ItemTaxGroup": 1,
    "ItemTotalTax": "0.10",
    "ItemTotalPrice": "1.10",
    "ItemSubProgram": 1,
    "ItemAccount": 1,
    "ItemActualCost": "1.00",
    "OrderID": 3
  }, {
    "OrderItemID": 19,
    "ItemDescription": "test",
    "ItemQty": 1,
    "ItemUnitPrice": "1.10",
    "ItemTaxGroup": 1,
    "ItemTotalTax": "0.10",
    "ItemTotalPrice": "1.10",
    "ItemSubProgram": 1,
    "ItemAccount": 1,
    "ItemActualCost": "1.00",
    "OrderID": 3
  }, {
    "OrderItemID": 20,
    "ItemDescription": "test",
    "ItemQty": 1,
    "ItemUnitPrice": "1.10",
    "ItemTaxGroup": 1,
    "ItemTotalTax": "0.10",
    "ItemTotalPrice": "1.10",
    "ItemSubProgram": 1,
    "ItemAccount": 1,
    "ItemActualCost": "1.00",
    "OrderID": 3
  }, {
    "OrderItemID": 21,
    "ItemDescription": "test",
    "ItemQty": 1,
    "ItemUnitPrice": "1.10",
    "ItemTaxGroup": 1,
    "ItemTotalTax": "0.10",
    "ItemTotalPrice": "1.10",
    "ItemSubProgram": 1,
    "ItemAccount": 1,
    "ItemActualCost": "1.00",
    "OrderID": 3
  }]
}
```

I thought the below might work:

```
http://localhost:29446/odata/OrderItems?$apply=aggregate(ItemTotalPrice with sum as Total)
```

but I get the following error:

```
The query parameter '$apply' is not supported.
```

I am using OData v4 with Web API 2.2

Answer (score 1):

The data aggregation extension is not yet implemented in Web API 2.2 for OData v4. There is a pull request for the ODataLib level implementation contributed on the Github repo of the .NET OData libraries: https://github.com/OData/odata.net/pull/6 but hasn't been merged into the master branch yet.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to implement your WebAPI controler, using the `.QueryByCube` LINQ operator ([www.adaptivelinq.com](http://www.adaptivelinq.com)).

Disclaimer: I'm the AdaptiveLINQ developer.